# How to overwrite the values in a properties file containing key value pair using ANT macro?

Tags: ant, properties, build.xml

I have two properties files

File 1 : Template.properties

1. k1=v1
2. k2=v2
3. k3=v3
4. k4=v4
5. k5=v5

File 2 : New.properties

1. k1=v11
2. k2=v22
3. k3=v33
4. k4=v44
5. k5=v55
6. k6=v66
7. k7=v77

I want to overwrite values of Template.properties with the values of New.properties and I don't want k6 and k7 in Template. How can i achieve this using ANT macro?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `copy` task with a `filterset`.  The template file should have @ around the replaceable values:

```
k1=@v1@
k2=@v2@
k3=@v3@
k4=@v4@
k5=@v5@
```

The use the filterset as follows

```
<filterset>
  <filter token="v1" value="v11"/>
   . . . 
</filterset>
```